# Automake ignores multiple source files for building a library

Tags: static-libraries, autotools

I am trying to create a static library with autotools however it only takes the cpp file with the same name of the library and ignores the other source files.

Makefile.am

```
AM_CXXFLAGS=-std=c++11
lib_LIBRARIES = mylib.a
mylib_a_SOURCES = dep1.cpp dep2.cpp mylib.cpp
```

automake and make do not complain but it only compiles mylib.cpp and turns it into a library. When I try to link against it I get errors such as

```
dep1.cpp undefined reference to dep1::method_name
```

Please help. I have been banging my head against the keyboard for hours. There are no tutorials on making libraries. The only autotool documentation I can find is either a 5 line hello world examples or 5000 page books with zero examples or context.

Comment: Can you post the actual linking command that your system executes? Try `make V=1` to see the details if you have put Automake in quiet mode.

Comment: I would always recommend passing 'dialect' options via the `CXX` variable: e.g., `CXX="g++ -std=c++11"` or `CXX="clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++"` - leave `CXXFLAGS` for optimization levels, architecture flags, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You are naming the _SOURCES variable incorrectly.  You want:

```
libmylib_a_SOURCES = ...
```

See the node in the Automake manual titled "Building a library"... this is in the first example.

I'm slightly surprised that Automake didn't give you a warning about a _SOURCES variable not corresponding to a known object.